# Get Azure users via REST APIs

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I want to fetch a list of Azure active users along with their set of permissions (role) via REST APIs.

So far I am not able to directly fetch them. I tried to figure them out using Active directory but no luck so far.

Here is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api) of Azure REST APIs

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which roles do you want to get? Their role for a subscription or their role for some resource group, or their role for some resource? Or do you want their role in Azure AD?

Comment: want users role at subscription level -

Comment: @juunas , did you find anything?

Comment: I did ;) Check my answer

Comment: @tom junnas answer is a good. But for PowerShell, you could get it more easily. If possible, you could try. `Get-AzureRmRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName "Owner" -Scope "/subscriptions/******"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft introduce Graph APIs for fetching user details and roles attached.
User Detail API:

https://graph.windows.net//users?api-version=1.6

Authorization:**Access Token**

**Access token** you can generate using resource as **https://graph.windows.net/** and authentication endpoint as **https://login.microsoftonline.com/**.

Note: You must have Microsoft Graph API Permission as well.

Below are some other graph API endpoints:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/directoryroles-operations

Directory roles:

https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/directoryRoles?api-version=1.6

List the users with roles:

https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/directoryRoles/ce8c598b-20eb-42b6-89c6-cf6c184ba416/$links/members?api-version=1.6

Answer (score 0):

You can get users' roles by querying the *role assignments* for the subscription.

Example URL:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/aaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments?$filter=atScope()&api-version=2015-07-01
```

You will need to put your subscription's id in there of course :)

`$filter=atScope()` is necessary to only get roles for the subscription, otherwise the request returns roles for resource groups and resources as well.

Example response:

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "roleDefinitionId": "/subscriptions/aaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/aaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa",
        "principalId": "aaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa",
        "scope": "/subscriptions/aaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa",
        "createdOn": "2018-03-04T19:38:21.9632037Z",
        "updatedOn": "2018-03-04T19:38:21.9632037Z",
        "createdBy": "aaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa",
        "updatedBy": "aaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa"
      },
      "id": "/subscriptions/aaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/aaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa",
      "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
      "name": "aaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa"
    }
  ]
}
```

`principalId` will be the `objectId` of the service principal, group, or user who this role was assigned to.

You will also need to find out what each role's id is.
Here I got the `roleDefinitionId` and used it to get the role's definition with another query like:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/aaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/aaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa?api-version=2015-07-01
```

And it responded with:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "roleName": "Contributor",
        "type": "BuiltInRole",
        "description": "Lets you manage everything except access to resources.",
        "assignableScopes": [
            "/"
        ],
        "permissions": [
            {
                "actions": [
                    "*"
                ],
                "notActions": [
                    "Microsoft.Authorization/*/Delete",
                    "Microsoft.Authorization/*/Write",
                    "Microsoft.Authorization/elevateAccess/Action"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "createdOn": "0001-01-01T08:00:00.0000000Z",
        "updatedOn": "2016-12-14T02:04:45.1393855Z",
        "createdBy": null,
        "updatedBy": null
    },
    "id": "/subscriptions/aaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/aaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa",
    "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions",
    "name": "aaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa"
}
```

You can also get all roles by leaving the id out.

- [Documentation - Role Definitions List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/authorization/roledefinitions/list)
- [Documentation - List Role Assignments for scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/authorization/roleassignments/listforscope)